# parsing military time into into HH MM and SS/

Tags: c, string

Say I have a time like this

```
12:34:56
```

How would I go about storing the parsed `integers` into a `char array`?(this is a requirement)

`argv[2]`  is the time passed in as a argument in the terminal.

This is what I have so far:

```
char *semi;
semi = strchr(argv[2],':')
&semi = '\0';
while(argv[2] != null){
```

By the way, this is in `C`. I'm aware other languages would make this easier.

Comment: read about `atoi` function

Comment: By the way, the expression `&semi = '\0'` does not do what you expect, if it will compile at all. Maybe you mean `*semi = '\0'`?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by "storing the parsed integers into a char array"? Should the individual values be stored as strings?

Comment: values will be converted into ints later with another function, parsed being broken into respective strings "12","34","56"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply put the null byte `'\0'` in place of the character `':'` in the string `argv[2]` and save pointers to the beginning of the hours, minutes and seconds part in the string.

```
// pointer to the start of the hour part
char *hh = argv[2];

char *mm, *ss;

char *temp = strchr(hh, ':');

// pointer to the start of the minute part
mm = temp + 1;

// null-terminate the hour part
*temp = '\0';

temp = strchr(mm, ':');

// pointer to the start of the second part
ss = temp + 1;

// null-terminate the minute part
*temp = '\0'; 

// print the hours, minutes and seconds part
printf("%s\n", hh);
printf("%s\n", mm);
printf("%s\n", ss);
```

`argv[2]` is a string, i.e., it is null-terminated, so the seconds part is already null-terminated.

Comment: I don't think it should segfault. Are you sure `argv[2]` contains the time string and not `argv[1]`?

Comment: yep, it seg faults when i try to print the ss

Comment: @ApprenticeProgrammer sorry. I had a mistake there. Please check. It should work now.

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply use [`sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)?

Like

```
char hh[3], mm[3], ss[3];
const char time[] = "12:34:56";

sscanf(time, "%2s:%2s:%2s", hh, mm, ss);
```

You should check the return value from `sscanf` for validation of the input.